# Has Influx 1.8.3 support for application/json body in InfluxDB API

Tags: javascript, http-headers, influxdb

On arm devices there is not available v2.0 build so far.

Is it possible to query db on v1.8.3 in similar way like this:

```
let response = await fetch('http://localhost:8086/query', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "db":"test",
    "q":"select * from measurement"
  })
});
```

Or application/x-www-form-urlencoded is the only applicable format for query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe the 1.x `/query` endpoint for `InfluxQL` queries only takes urlencoded data. See these docs: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/api/#query-http-endpoint

You can use `URLSearchParams` in the `fetch` api to set url query params.

Comment: Thanks, URLSearchParams is what I was looking for